# why is a different class allowed in a function call in typescript

Tags: typescript

I thought that typescript did checks on parameters passed into functions.

I was therefore surprised when the code below compiled and ran without error.

```
class Foo {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

class Bar {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string;
}

const y = new Bar();

y.a = 'a';
y.b = 'b';
y.c = 'c';
y.d = 'd';

const x = (options: Foo) => {
    console.log(options);
};

x(y);
```

I expected the editor (vscode) and the compiler to flag that `Foo` class is not the same as `Bar` class

Whilst I am not a typescript guru, the fact that I was surprised has made me ask this question. I would like to understand the reasons why this is allowed so that I can learn not to make the same mistake again.

Comment: Typescript is *structurally*, not *nominally* typed - a Bar has all the properties a Foo does, so anything that accepts a Foo can work with a Bar too.

Comment: Also known as 'duck' typing...